# How is the list of apps allowed to install another apps populated?

Tags: 8.1-oreo

On Android 8.1,

If I go to `"Settings" > "Apps & Notifications" > "Advanced" > "Special App Access" > "Install unknown apps"`, what determines which app are in this list ?

On my phone, I see :
`Chrome, Drive, Files, GMail, Messanger, WhatsApp`.

Yet I have a lot more apps installed and running.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It lists apps that have the permission to install other apps. The permission is found on the apps' manifest. For example, a file manager can install an apk, same case with a browser or Whatsapp if a contact sends an apk to you.

They are labelled Unknown apps because the apps are not installed via Google Play Store, thus not trusted by Google (that does not mean that there is something wrong with the file).

From @Andrew T's comment, the permission is [REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES) that:

> Allows an application to request installing packages. Apps targeting APIs greater than 25 must hold this permission in order to use Intent.ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE.

**Note:** API 25 is for Android 8.

Comment: Looks like the specific permission is [REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES) (from [Stack Overflow - How to manage installation from Unknown Sources in Android Oreo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49828745))

Comment: @AndrewT. Edited and added your useful information.

Comment: Yes it was the permission REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES, thank you

Comment: @madgangmixers AndrewT is the one who found the permission's name not me.

Answer (score 5):

Just to add some related details to @ReddyLutonadio's [answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/216086/218526), [`android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES) is the one which defines which apps would appear in the list you have mentioned, and it's [required](https://source.android.com/compatibility/8.0/android-8.0-cdd#4_application_packaging_compatibility) on Android 8+ to install apps from sources other than Google Play. But this permission alone doesn't define if the app is allowed to install unknown packages or not. It has protection level [`Signature`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview#signature_permissions):

> The system grants these app permissions at install time, but only when the app that attempts to use a permission is signed by the same certificate as the app that defines the permission.

It means that user apps will never be allowed this permission. The apps which are allowed in `"Settings" > "Apps & Notifications" > "Advanced" > "Special App Access" > "Install unknown apps"` are those which have AppOps operation [`OP_REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r47/core/java/android/app/AppOpsManager.java#647) allowed. You can also check from `adb shell`:

```
~$ appops query-op REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES allow
```

Results must be same as in Settings. To deny any of the apps:

```
~$ appops set org.fdroid.fdroid REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES deny
```

And it will appear as `Not allowed` in Settings.

Other permissions which are controlled with AppOps can be seen with `dumpsys package | grep -A100 'AppOp Permissions:' | sed '/^$/q'`.

---

**RELATED:**

- [How to grant an app a permission that isn't in its manifest?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/217522/218526)